# Geocoding block using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding

The address table that I am trying to geocode does not have specific addresses; rather, it has blocks (e.g. 200 Block FIRESTONE LN).

Is it possible for me to still geocode the table?

I can't just open the table in Excel and remove all mentions of "Block", as I then wouldn't have actual existing addresses for most of my table (200 FIRESTONE LN is not an address).

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2.

Comment: Can you be specific as to how you are geocoding? Are you using a pre-made locator, or making one based on your own dataset?

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @ChrisW](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139036/geocoding-block-using-arcgis-desktop#comment200889_139036):

> Technically 200 Firestone Ln is an address - the first point on the
>   200 block of that road. It may not be a *mailing* address, as perhaps
>   house numbers start at 210. So there's basically two problems you have
>   to decide on an approach to. First, if you have multiple addresses in
>   the 200 block, there's no way to separate them and they'll get the
>   same point. Second, the geocoder has an address range for each street
>   segment. It *might* be a pattern like 200-299, and you could use 250
>   to stick it in the middle. But if you want valid mailing address
>   results, no, you don't have enough info.