# Geocoding Adresses with varying levels of reporting accuracy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, accuracy

I am trying to geocode a database that has, I'll call it "4 tiers", of address types.

They are:

- Numbered Street (e.g. 506 Taproom Way)
- Cross-street (Happy Road $ Jubilant Blvd)
- Hundreds Block (500 block Cranberry St)
- Road (Independence Blvd)

I have added a field that classes each tier.

The dataset in question is crowd-sourced (thus, a bit messy) that has compiled incidents where an individual has died from interaction with law enforcement (police use of deadly force). So, I would liken this data to crime type data, but from the opposite perspective. I am validating the dataset and doing hotspot analysis. That is why I want to Geocode the addresses (using ArcMap 10.2).

The first 2 tiers will have an acceptable positional error, but the other two tier (hundreds block and Road) will have greater error. For crime type analysis what type of positional error is acceptable? Is there a way of dealing with the less accurate tiers? Would changing the points to polygons (blocks) or polylines (roads) that represent the incident be better?

Comment: @Lfarman It appears you have created two accounts - you should see about [merging them](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Please note while your edit does provide some good additional information and context, you're also adding to the question and GIS.SE generally works best with a focused, specific, one-question-per-question format. I wouldn't change blocks to polygons - maybe lines. But it depends on your analysis method and the area covered. If say city-wide, then a point anywhere along a block is probably fine. I think the fourth tier would just have to be thrown out.

Answer (score 1):

- The numbered street records are standard and not a problem assuming a
  match can be found in the geocoder/source data. Depending on the
  service, accuracy should be very high. Some are based on actual point
  or parcel locations. Others simply use percentage length of the line
  and the range for that line to establish where along the line to put
  the point.
- Cross streets can also be handled by many geocoders, but you have
  additional complications. First, it's a cross street and not an
  address, so either it doesn't represent an actual point or you don't
  know which corner it belongs to. Second, it's possible for the same
  streets to intersect more than once, so you end up with multiple
  choices and no way to decide without further info.
- Blocks become problematic, because now you don't have a specific
  point at all. From my comment on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139036/is-is-possible-to-geocode-a-block), modified to fit
  your example: You can't just use the block number because 500
  Cranberry St is an address - the first point on the 500 block of that
  road. It may not be a mailing address, as perhaps house numbers start
  at 510. So there's basically two problems you have to decide on an
  approach to. First, if you have multiple addresses in the 500 block,
  there's no way to separate them and they'll get the same point.
  Second, the geocoder has an address range for each street segment. It
  might be a pattern like 500-599, and you could use 550 to stick it in
  the middle (or use beginning or ending range number to put it on one
  end or the other). In either case, the point won't be at the actual
  location. How (in)accurate it is would depend on how long the block
  is.
- With a road only, there's pretty much no point. Only in cases where
  the road is just a one block long section like a cul-de-sac or
  something could you get any kind of reliable match. Otherwise the
  point could fall anywhere along the road, however long it is through
  the city. At best prefixes or suffixes might eliminate half the road
  (ie South vs North Independence). Much like with blocks, a point can be placed at beginning, middle, or end and that's about it.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'relative error for each tier'. If you mean in finding a match at all with the geocoding service, that's one thing. If you mean between the geocoded point and the *actual* point, you'd have to have actual points to compare to and only your first tier gives those unless just getting it at the right intersection or on the right block is sufficient to call it accurate. You'd need another source than the geocoder to compare against, like an address map and imagery or something. Or be UPS, who is known to collect GPS points literally on the doorstep of the address at time of delivery.

My first suggestion would be to split the database up or at the very least add a new field that flags the address type and focus on geocoding each type individually. You could also (depending on service) use a compound locator - meaning it uses a street locator first, finds no match and tries a cross street locator, finds no match and tries whatever method you determine to handle blocks, etc. Providing more information about what software or service you're using may lead to more specific techniques or steps to address the problem tiers.

Answer (score 0):

Chris W is on the mark, especially on the final two points. A hundred block is of limited valuable and a street name without a number at all is only useful if there are just one or two blocks to the street. As he indicated, treat each "class" separately, though the first two likely can be run together depending on the locator style. E.g., a US Streets style locator (Esri-speak) can handle both # name or street #1 @ street #2 type data. Cheers.